# how to get this for loop to execute only for 1 out of every 100 files?

Tags: batch-file

I need this for loop to run for 1 in ~every 100 files...

```
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('dir /s /b /a-d 2^>nul') do if "%time:~9,2%"=="77" echo process "%%v"
```

problem is that the same number is assigned for all the files, so the whole set of files is skipped with ~1:100 chance of all files getting processed.

Comment: "every hundreth file" or "about 1% random files"?

Comment: about 1% (current method) is totally fine. any method where it's random is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
  set /a rnd=!random! %% 100
  rem echo !rnd!
  if !rnd! == 0 ECHO process "%%~fa" 
)
```

`rnd` is generated to hold a number between 0 and 99. So the `if` triggers with a probability of 1% per file (use `if !rnd! lss 25 ...` for a probability of 25%).
This gives you 1% of your files *in average*.

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas.

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    echo(
    echo Case 1, one file each 100
    echo(

    rem Initialize counter variable. 
    rem Here two options, fixed start or random start
    set "n=0"
    set /a "n= %random% %% 100"

    rem While hidding stderr
        rem For each file
            rem Increase the counter and calculate 1 / n mod 100
            rem Calc will fail if n is a multiple of 100
            rem Use conditional execution operator to detect failure and 
            rem echo the file name

    2>nul (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d') do (
            set /a "n+=1", "1/(n %% 100)" || echo %%a
        )
    )

    echo(
    echo Case 2, random file selection with a 1/100 probability
    echo( 

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    2>nul (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d') do (
            set /a  "1/(!random! * 100 / 32768)" || (
                setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
                echo %%a
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal 

    echo(
    echo Case 3, random 1/100 file selection 
    echo(

    rem Generate a list of files with a random prefix, sort the list and then 
    rem retrieve one file each 100 with the same method in case 1

    set "n=0"
    2>nul (
        for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('
            dir /s /b /a-d 
            ^| cmd /q /e /v /c"for /f delims^= %%a in ('find /v ""') do set /a !random! & echo  %%a"
            ^| sort
        ') do (
            set /a "n+=1", "1/(n %% 100)" || echo %%b
        )
    )
```

Comment: +1, I was going to post a solution very similar to your Case 1. Note that you can use `set /a "1/((n+=1)%%100)"`

Comment: @dbenham, Amazing! I never though about placing the assignment inside the operation.